# Does the discard get shuffled into the deck when adding the heat up card?

Tags: dark-souls

When adding the heat up card to the boss deck, do you shuffle in the discard pile as well, or just shuffle it into the remaining cards that haven't been revealed?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it specifies in the rule book that the shuffling of the boss deck means you have to relearn the Boss's pattern. If you only shuffled the deck (not discard) it would be trivial to wait until the entire deck was in the discard, then do the final damage to "heat up" maintaining exactly the same order for the rest of the deck, with the heat up card being next (and therefore last).

Comment: I don't know that is necessarily an advantage.  We specifically chose to take the fully randomized deck (by waiting until it was refreshed before heating up) to buy the likelihood that the heat up card on average would show up a few turns later and not immediately.  They seem to be potentially fair trade offs depending what state the characters are in, whether they want to face a heat up immediately (when the discard is full and you have the option to heat up right away).